# Bind to service from android activity

Tags: android, service

I have an Activity that starts a service. When the activity is closed, I want the service to continue running in the background. I have a couple of questions here.

Will closing the activity screen cause the activity to actually stop? Or do I need to forcibly stop it to cause it to stop?

If closing the screen does cause it to stop, then I assume I need to use `startService` to start it. Is that correct? If that is the case, is there a way to get a handle to the running service next time the activity starts? If it is not the case, then I can just bind to the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your `Activity` is no longer visible on the screen, it is stopped.  Stopping an `Activity` bound to a `Service` does not stop the `Service`.  However, you'll want to make sure you unbind from the `Service` when your `Activity` calls `onDestroy()` to make sure you don't have any dangling handlers and suchlike.

You can rebind to a running `Service` the same way as you did the first time.  Sending an `Intent` to start a `Service` that's already running doesn't create a second instance of it, so that's safe.

A good way to start a `Service` like you're describing is to start it using the `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` argument to your call to `bindService()`.

The details of all of this can be found at the [Android docs about bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html).  It can be a little confusing at first.  Follow the tutorial code closely since it sounds like your problem maps well onto the sample they provide.

Comment: Yep, I think you answered that perfectly. Thanks. I have been reading those docs, but this is good clarification. As a quick follow up (maybe I should open another question). After I bind to the service, it doesn't look like I need to start it (its onCreate method is called automatically). Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct.  The `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` argument ensures that it gets started if it's not already.  Indeed, you cannot bind to a service that's not started, so the service is started before the binding happens.